# How to Zip a Series of 2 files with same prefix names in a folder?

Tags: command-line, 7-zip

I ran the following command to zip a series of folders in one main folder.

FOR /D %i IN (C:\source*) DO 7z.exe a "C:\destination\%~ni.7z" "%i" -stl -mx=5 -mhe -mtc -bb > c:\destination\"%~ni output.doc"

File Name 1.7z
File Name 1 Directory.doc
File Name 2.7z
File Name 2 Directory.doc

Now in that destination folder, I have the zipped file and the table of contents output.doc file.  Each zipped file and output file have the same name as you can see.

I now want to take each zipped file and table of contents document for that zipped file and combine them into a second, password protected zip file.

I want to combine these two into one new zipped password file:
File Name 1.7z
File Name 1 Directory.doc

Then there should be a second new zipped password file with these, and so on:
File Name 2.7z
File Name 2 Directory.doc

How can I do that?